# IF and AND statement #value error

Tags: excel, countif

I have a spreadsheet with a list of dates like this:

```
    Date1     Date2    Date3    Date4   Date5   Score
    1/1/15   1/2/15    1/3/15   1/4/15   1/5/15    14
```

I want to make another column that will be a binary (1,0) if all of the dates 1-5 are more than 6 months from today AND if the score is less than 15.

I tried to use this IF/AND statement:

```
   =IF(AND(C2:C7>TODAY()-180, V2<15),1,0)
```

where C2:C7 is the range of dates, and V2 is the score.

This is pulling a #value error.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lrk889, I took your  Formula and test it and it worked fine. you get the value error when you do not press ctrl+shift+enter on array commands.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like...

```
  =IF(AND(COUNTIF(A2:E2,">"&TODAY()-180)=0,F2<15),1,0)
```

[image]

to handle additional date ranges...  Notice I've broken this down so you can see the different AND statements

```
 =IF(AND
       (COUNTIF(A2:E2,">"&TODAY()-180)=0,
        F2<15,
        countif(C10:c14,">"&Today()-180)=0)
     ,1,0)
```

Comment: That works! I was wondering if you knew how to add another date range to this formula? IE: If I had dates in c10:c14 that would follow the same rule as the today()-180?

Comment: @lrk889  example added at end, you can add as many and conditions in as you want just have to put them in at the right place after each one.  I've broken the above into separate lines to help you visualize the breakdown of the "And" statement